# how to filter specific values out of an array?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Hi I have an array as below

```
 "data": [
{
  "title": "title1",
  "category": "apple"
},
{
  "title": "title2",
  "category": "bannana"
}, 
{
  "title": "title3",
  "category": "grape"
}
]
```

etc

I have a var like below

```
$categories = 'bannana, grape';
```

I have a loop which runs through the data and extracts *all* of the titles.

What I'm trying to achieve is a loop which will go through the array and only extract titles where the category matches one of the values in $categories variable.

so in this case the title1 will be ignored as it is in the category apple. but title2 and title3 would be added to a new array or put in a string, etc.

Any help on where to begin with this is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Say, isn't that `banana`? *Just saying* ;-) It'll save you a keystroke.

Comment: `explode()` is key function for you, it will help you convert string to array, then it is easy to check if value is in array or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple

```
$categories = 'bannana, grape';
$categories = array_flip(array_map("trim", explode(",", $categories)));

$data = array_filter($data, function ($v) use($categories) {
    return isset($categories[$v['category']]);
});
var_dump($data);
```

[See Live DEMO](https://eval.in/33574)

Comment: Best answer if you have a large number of categories and data.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) the `data` array and use [`in_array`](http://php.net/in_array) to verify the title contains one of your categories, see below:

**PHP Example**

```
$categories = "banana, grape";
$data = [
    [
        'title' => 'title1',
        'category' => 'apple',
    ],
    [
        'title' => 'title2',
        'category' => 'banana',
    ],
    [
        'title' => 'title3',
        'category' => 'grape',
    ],
];

$category_map = explode(", ", $categories);

foreach($data as $title) {
    if(in_array($title['category'], $category_map)) {
        echo $title['category'] . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

**Example Returns**

```
banana
grape
```

Comment: (`+1`) <= for code and the proper spelling of **banana**. You just have to love the keystroke reduction `method()`. Cheers ;-) Now I'm hungry. All this talk about food, makes me want to go and make me **fruit salad!**

Answer (score 0):

To filter an array use array_filter with a closure.

```
$categoriesArray = explode(",", $categories);
$filtered = array_filter($data, function($a) use ($categoriesArray){
     return in_array($a["category"], $categoriesArray);
});

foreach($filtered as $topic){
      echo $topic["category"]."<br/>";
}
```